# Get all the links on a php webpage using c++

Tags: php, c++, hyperlink

I know basic c++ and Qt. I want to know how can I get all the links on a processed php webpage, please explain briefly and suggest some online resources.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you accessing the PHP source, or the processed web page? In the latter case PHP has nothing to do with it, and I would suggest searching for an XML or HTML parser library.

Comment: In addition to Biffen's XML parser library suggestion: Qt has already good on-board functionality for XML. Check out the QDomDocument or the StreamReader.